# Chrome.windows.create not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my content script I do

`chrome.windows.create({url: "local.html", type: "popup"});`

however, no window ever shows up.

Do I need to change my manifest file first? Why doesn't this function create a new window ever?

I have tabs enabled like so

```
{
  "name": "Tool",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "",
  "homepage_url": "",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/on.png",
    "48": "icons/on.png",
    "128": "icons/on.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "page": "src/bg/background.html",
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/on.png",
    "default_title": "browser action demo"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>","tabs", "webNavigation"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
  {
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
       "src/lib/jquery.min.js", "src/inject/inject.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "src/inject/inject.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's likely that you need to add the `tabs` permission to your manifest.

Comment: @JordanFitz I have tabs enabled in my permissions ` "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>","tabs", "webNavigation"
  ],`

Comment: The chrome developer page says this: `create − chrome.windows.create(object createData, function callback)`. Maybe you're missing the callback?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend checking out the console, it will likely have relevant errors.

Comment: @JordanFitz ` Cannot read property 'create' of undefined ` chrome is undefined??

Comment: That means chrome.windows is undefined. What file is your script in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to call this from the content script.

Quoting the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)

If you need to initiate some action that uses Chrome API from the content script, you have to message your background script to do this. See [Architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) and [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: ohhh i see. so the only way I can pass informatino to background script is by messaging it.

Comment: Technically, there's also `chrome.storage` API, accessible from both and firing change events.